# How to get paginated results (async query) from bigquery python client?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I was using Python client for BigQuery in App Engine project. I've gone through the documentation [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/bigquery-query.html) but was unable to understand how to get next batch of results using QueryResults class - fetch_data() method using pageToken

fetch_data() method returns (row_data, total_rows, page_token) according to [documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/bigquery-query.html#google.cloud.bigquery.query.QueryResults.fetch_data) but in My experimentation it returns only row_data nothing else, moreover total_rows and page_token are also not returned even though there are more results that can be retrieved on next page of the query result.

Please share code snippet if you have done pagination before for retrieving no. of results from bigquery at a time.